# Laravel CSRF protection exception now working

Tags: php, laravel, csrf, csrf-token

My Laravel project is in this link

```
http://localhost/demo/public // laravel project
```

and I have this external HTML form

```
http://localhost/attendance
```

Now I want to send data from the form to Laravel 
but I got this error

> 419
>       Page Expired

so in my laravel project VerifyCsrfToken Class I wrote this

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'http://localhost/attendance'
    ];
}
```

but still, got the same error

> 419 Page Expired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel resolve for you the baseUrl of your application, there is no need to put the full path, in your case the Middleware should be like below:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'attendance/*'
    ];
}
```

Comment: did that now working the same attendance files not connected with demo files

Comment: you want to expect csrf_token from all urls project or just from attendance or from the sublinks of attendance?

Comment: just from the sublinks of attendance

Comment: if attendance group sublinks within your app, check my edit answer, please

Comment: no attendance  is different application and its not sublink with the application

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195200/discussion-between-thamer-belfkih-and-softya).

Answer (score 1):

- One solution would be to send the data as a GET request instead of a POST one.
- Once you put your work online, you would face cross-site protection on the browser.
- The `URI` to be excluded is the one receiving the request so `http://localhost/demo/public`

Comment: sometime the data is more than 1000 so like that it will open 1000 browser and i dont want to work like that i tried that before